# Subgroups needing more generators in number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let G be an odd order group such that [G,G] is central. If G is a 2-generator group, can it have a 3-generator subgroup?

This can't happen if G is abelian.
I tried to go for p-groups but their classification wasn't very helpful.
Next, I looked for the smallest order but I didn't pass 33.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $G=\langle x,y,z\mid x^9=y^9=z^9=1, xz=zx, yz=zy, yx=xyz\rangle$. Then look at $H=\langle x^3,y^3,z\rangle$.

Comment: Smallest group is probably of order $p^4$: $\langle x,y,z\mid x^{p^2}=y^p=z^p=1, xz=zx, yz=zy, yx=xyz\rangle$, with $H=\langle x^p,y,z\rangle$.

Comment: I'm not very good with generators and relations, but I can more or less see that your example is correct. Is the given group a semidirect product or a matrix group? Why that group has order p^4? Why do you think the smallest overall example has order 81? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that you can realize the first group as a group of $3\times 3$ upper triangular matrices with $1$s in the diagonal and entries in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$, with $x$ corresponding to $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)$, $y$ to $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)$, and $z=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)$. For the second group, take the $(1,2)$ entry in $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, and the $(1,3)$ and $(2,3)$ entries in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Groups of order $p^2$ are abelian, so they don't give you the example you want. The nonabelian groups of order $p^3$ don't have "enough room" for an example: proper subgroups are abelian of order at most $p^2$, hence $2$-generated or cyclic. My second example is of order $p^4$, hence that's the smallest. It has order $p^4$ because every element can be written as $x^ay^bz^c$ with $0\leq a\lt p^2$, $0\leq b\lt p$, $0\leq c\lt p$, so you have $p^2pp=p^4$ elements.

Comment: Finally, groups with $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$ are nilpotent, so they are the product of their Sylow $p$-subgroups. Any example will then reduce to a $p$-group, so the smallest order possible should be $p^4$.

Comment: Thanks, Arturo!

Comment: Every 2-generator group is 3-generator. If by 3-generator you mean that the generating rank is $\ge 3$, you should at least write it explicitly, and, better, use a less confusing terminology.